# How to use str_replace in Laravel Dynamic route

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to create a dynamic url from my title in laravel routes.

I tried to use such as :

```
Route::get('/page/{strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $bank->bank_name))}', 'BankController@show');
```

But this code gives me 404 error. I tried to google but unable to find anything useful.

ANyone who could help?

Comment: You have to use `strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $bank->bank_name))`  in your view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should look like this:

```
Route::get('/page/{BankName}', 'BankController@show');
```

Inside your controller show function:

```php
public function show($BankName){
    $BankName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $BankName));
}
```

To check if it works in Routes, you can try:

```
Route::get('/Page/{BankName}', function ($BankName){
    echo strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $BankName));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
Route::get('/page/{your_name?}', 'BankController@show');
```

In your view you have to use

```
href="{{ url('') }}/page/{{strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $bank->bank_name))}}
```